# Describe explicitly $\text{spec}(\mathbb{R}[x])$ and $\text{spec}(\mathbb{C}[x])$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, zariski-topology, polynomial-rings

Describe explicitly $\text{spec}(\mathbb{R}[x])$ and $\text{spec}(\mathbb{C}[x])$, (where for a given ring $R$, $\text{spec}(R)$ is defined to be the set of all prime ideals of $R$).

I don't have an attampt or something to start with.

Comment: You can start with the definition of $\operatorname{Spec}$.

Comment: For a given ring $R$, $\text{spec}(R)$ is defined to be the set of all prime ideals of $R$. @lisyarus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F = \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.  Since $F$ is a field, $F[x]$ is a principal ideal domain.  What can you say about the prime ideals in a principal ideal domain?

Comment: $F[x]$ is a PID thus each prine ideal is generated by an irreducible polynom, thanks.